# Catch exceptions from third party directives used in template

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular2-template, angular-directive

I am using `angular-google-charts` library im my Angular application.
 I use it in my template:

```
<google-chart
  [title]="chart.title"
  [type]="chart.type"
  [data]="chart.data">
</google-chart>
```

If the user is offline, google-chart throws an exception as internet connection is required. I solved this issue by wrapping the directive in an `*ngIf` and checked if there is network connectivity or less.

 **However, in a more generic context, how could I catch exceptions from third party directives that are used only in the template?**

Is a global error handling the only possibility?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid so. You can operate some filtering in the `ErrorHandler` btw, according to the specific library exception. 
If a particular exception is declared by the third-party application, you could check it with `instanceof ThirdPartyExceptionType`.

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { ThirdPartyExceptionType } from 'thirdpartylibrary';

export class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  handleError(error: Error | ThirdPartyExceptionType ) {   
   if (error instanceof ThirdPartyExceptionType ) {
      // do something
   } else {
     // do something else
   }
}
```